# Lazy-loading TreeNodes while searching a TreeView as fast as possible

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to build a registry editor in C# WinForms and am struggling to match the searching performance of Windows' built-in regedit.exe. My only gripe with that program for many years has been that you can't type in a full key path and be taken straight to that key, so I decided to implement this functionality (along with a few other minor improvements) into my own program.

The first hurdle that I had to overcome was developing a method to read the 10K or so keys in a typical Windows registry and display them to the user. From what I've read on here and other websites and tried, it seems the fastest way to do this is to "lazy-load" the keys into a TreeView. So my program starts by loading just five hive key TreeNodes into a TreeView along with a dummy child for each one so they can be expanded. Then as the user expands nodes their children are loaded as well.

This works relatively well, but the second challenge is now to be able to find all keys whose names partially match a given string. This is synonymous to regedit.exe's F3 search with only "Keys" checked and "Match whole string only" unchecked. I believe this performs a linear depth-first search of the currently selected registry key and those below it, then loops around to those before it. So I originally thought that in my program, it is inevitable that any search will require a lot of extra loading on the fly, completely obliterating the performance benefits gained from lazy-loading.

I then realised that on every search iteration, I could collate just the nodes that matched and add them all to the TreeView at the end. This improves things greatly but it's still taking roughly 2 mins for my average-by-modern-standards computer to search the entire registry for a string that doesn't exist anywhere, and roughly 2 - 5 seconds for each occurrence of "software" to be found. regedit.exe seems to be faster by a factor of 0.5 or so.

So can anyone give me any tips on how I could make this faster? Here's the [full project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64884336/RegEditor.zip) for anyone that wants to take a closer look. MTIA :-)